# TFS2012 - cannot upload files larger than 5MB

Tags: tfs

I am running a TFS 2012 installation on a virtual machine (inside Windows Azure). Everything works fine, except that files bigger than 5MB cannot be checked in. On the client side it says: "The request was aborted: The request was canceled.".

On the server side the event log contains an error saying:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="TFS Services" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">4000</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-07-02T15:57:04.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>1832</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>gm-tfsserver</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation component or extension: Date (UTC): 02/07/2013 15:57:04 Machine: GM-TFSSERVER Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/tfs-2-130172535704544600 Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v4.0.30319 Service Host: 7e62b8c5-5065-4b32-9734-fc37fac35a8c (GM) Process Details: Process Name: w3wp Process Id: 3636 Thread Id: 3232 Account name: GM-TFSSERVER\Christian Detailed Message: TF30065: An unhandled exception occurred. Web Request Details Url: http://gm-tfsserver:8080/tfs/GM/VersionControl/v1.0/upload.ashx [method: POST] User Agent: Team Foundation (devenv.exe, 11.0.60610.1, Ultimate, SKU:8) Headers: Content-Length=16778221&Content-Type=multipart%2fform-data%3b+boundary%3d--------------------------8e5m2D6l5Q4h6&Accept-Language=en-GB&Expect=100-continue&Host=gm-tfsserver%3a8080&User-Agent=Team+Foundation+(devenv.exe%2c+11.0.60610.1%2c+Ultimate%2c+SKU%3a8)&X-TFS-Version=1.0.0.0&X-TFS-Session=2801ee9b-62f2-43e9-9a65-c296978716df Path: /tfs/GM/VersionControl/v1.0/upload.ashx Local Request: False Host Address: 77.177.87.232 User: GM-TFSSERVER\Christian [authentication type: NTLM] Exception Message: TF14109: Parts of the file $/GM Software/Legacy Code/Gw Code/GrData.txt were not uploaded. (type IncompleteUploadException) Exception Stack Trace: at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server.UploadHandler.ParseRequestParameters(VersionControlRequestContext versionControlRequestContext, String& workspaceName, String& workspaceOwner, String& serverItem, Byte[]& hash, HttpPostedFile& file, Int64& fileLength, Int64& compressedLength, Int64& offsetFrom, CompressionType& compressionType) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server.UploadHandler.Execute()</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

I tested it with two different internet connections from two different locations. The Virtual machine has port 8080 opened in the azure endpoint configuration.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Through the client side I tried the following solution which solve my problem with

> The request was aborted: The request was canceled.

by adding the app setting key `VersionControl.UploadChunkSize` to devenv.exe.config (%Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE)

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="VersionControl.UploadChunkSize" value="1048576" />
</appSettings>
```

I figured this from this answer: [TFS check in timeout of changeset containing "larger" binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992469/tfs-check-in-timeout-of-changeset-containing-larger-binary-files/18992760#18992760)
Please have a look to the link to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look for **deltaMaxFileSize** in the `web.config` file.

**[Link](http://teamfoundation.blogspot.in/2007/07/maximum-size-of-file-under-source.html)**

Comment: I cannot find the web.config that is mentioned in that link. I don't even have a Team Foundation Server folder on my client. Also on the server side, there is no web.config with this setting.