# TFS - Not able to checkin Video files in server

Tags: asp.net, tfs, checkin

Iam able to checkin normal files in TFS but when iam trying to check in a video file of arounf 25 mb then inially it takes time but finally says that request is aborted.
Please help.

[image]

Comment: If there is no permission and privacy issues. Could you share this special video file for test?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any reason of file types could cause an upload issue. Otherwise, it should have to be known since so many people are using TFS. Please make sure this file is not in use with other application

To narrow down this issue, you can do some test as below:

- Check in another video file
- Check in this file to another team project
- Check in this file with another user account
- Try other methods with the upload (such as drag and drop or used the
  browse button to attach the file )
- Try to upload this file in work item

Answer (score 0):

Try with the solution in this question: [TFS check in timeout of changeset containing “larger” binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992469/tfs-check-in-timeout-of-changeset-containing-larger-binary-files/18992760#18992760).

> So, I added this to TfsMigrationShell.exe.config
>
> ```
> <appSettings>
>     <add key="VersionControl.UploadChunkSize" value="2097152" /> 
> </appSettings
> ```

Another similar question: [TFS2012 - cannot upload files larger than 5MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441943/tfs2012-cannot-upload-files-larger-than-5mb).